# c# how to insert into database

Tags: c#, mysql

I need help on this, I'm inserting file directory into the database but it does not take into account of the txtStoryTitle.Text in the database, for example, if I type HelloWorld in txtStoryTitle. It appears as Images/Story//(filename) instead of Images/Story/HelloWorld/(filename) in the DB. I am using MySQL (workbench).

please give me an advice/solutions on this, thanks in advance!

Here are the partial codes:

```
    protected void AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
        EnsureDirectoriesExist();


        String filepathImage = (@"Images/Story/" + txtStoryTitle.Text + "/" + e.FileName);


        AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(filepathImage));


        Session["filepathImage"] = filepathImage;

    }

   public void EnsureDirectoriesExist()
    {
        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(@"Images/Story/" + txtStoryTitle.Text + "/")))
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(@"Images/Story/" + txtStoryTitle.Text + "/"));
        }
    }

 protected void btnDone_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["filepathImage"] != null)
        {
            string filepathImage = Session["filepathImage"] as string;
            act.ActivityName = dropListActivity.SelectedItem.Text;
            act.Title = txtStoryTitle.Text;

            act.FileURL = filepathImage;

            daoStory.Insert(act);
            daoStory.Save();

        }
```

Comment: Can you show what the view looks like - especially the control named 'txtStoryTitle'

Comment: what is `daoStory` and show the code of `daoStory.Insert` method?

Comment: Check do you get anything from txtStoryTitle.Text! As I see it, you get empty string, that's why it appears as Images/Story//(filename)

Comment: sorry i didnt state in the post , i am using entity framework , so daoStory is a class where i have my CRUD codes in it . @Sylca please enlighten me on this , thanks !

Comment: in my other web form , it works fine but its a single upload .

Comment: and i tested by using Label like this Label1.Text = txtStoryTitle.Text . it works fine , there is string in it .

Answer (score 1):

As per your code.. the file path is "Images/Story/" + txtStoryTitle.Text + "/" + e.FileName"
and after providing txtStoryTitle.Text it saved as "Images/Story//FileName".. then it means txtStoryTitle.Text does'nt contain any text..

If its in .Net then make sure you set **autopostback** property of txtStoryTitle textbox to true.
and if it is already true then try to find out why this textbox does'nt resist its state.